# What is printf's behaviour when printing an int as float?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, int, printf

I am using dev cpp on windows7 to compile my code.

```
int d = 0x12;
char* e = (char*)&d;
printf("%d %d\n", sizeof (int), sizeof (float));
printf("%p %p\n", &d, (float*)&d);
printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", &d, &e[0], &e[1], &e[2], &e[3]);
printf(" %d | %x | %#1x | %#1x | %#1x |%p\n", d,  e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], &e[0]);
getchar();

4 4 
0028FF40 0028FF40
0028FF40 0028FF40 0028FF41 0028FF42 0028FF43  
18 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |0028FF40
```

You  an see that if I use %d for printing d, it is printing the 4 bytes of e fine. But if I use %f like below, it shows  zeros in the place where the first byte of e have to be printed. Anyone can help with why this happens? Why should e's contents depend on how d is formatted?

```
int d = 0x12;
char* e = (char*)&d;
printf("%d %d\n", sizeof (int), sizeof (float));
printf("%p %p\n", &d, (float*)&d);
printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", &d, &e[0], &e[1], &e[2], &e[3]);
printf(" %f | %x | %#1x | %#1x | %#1x |%p\n", d,  e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], &e[0]);
getchar();
```

The output is:

```
4 4
0028FF40 0028FF40
0028FF40 0028FF40 0028FF41 0028FF42 0028FF43
 0.000000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0x28ff40 |76869F1D
```

Comment: You should stop using Dev-Cpp. It's extremely outdated and uses an ancient version of GCC.

Comment: Why are you casting `(int*)` to `(float*)`? Programming is hard enough as it is without stuff like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can happen if printf is called with a wrong format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504148/what-can-happen-if-printf-is-called-with-a-wrong-format-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Undefined behaviour.

In practice, what you're seeing is probably due to the fact that `%f` makes `printf` pull a `double` from its argument list, which is 8 bytes<sup>*</sup>.  But `d` is only 4 bytes in size, so now everything is misaligned.

Remember that `printf` is a variadic function, which means it's completely non-type-safe; `printf` has to extract raw bytes from the stack without any help from the compiler.  It's entirely up to you to ensure that the arguments correspond precisely to the format string.

---

<sub>* Probably.</sub>

Comment: I took your answer as meaning that the bytes of e are still there but it is just that it reads them from wrong place. I could verify with by making a casted printf in the next line.                                        printf(" %f | %x | %#1x | %#1x | %#1x |%p\n", (float)d,  e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], &e[0]);
This actually gave the right results. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting tripped up by automatic type promotion.

You seem to be assuming that since sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), you can pass d as a float or an int interchangeably.  But the thing is, in C you can't pass a float.

In C, when you use a char or a short in an expression, it is automatically converted into an int.  Similarly, when you use a float in an expression, it is automatically converted into a double.

So, when you do a printf("%f", d), the compiler pushes an int, that is to say, four bytes, onto the stack, before making the function call.  Then in the function, printf() sees "%f", and pulls eight bytes off the stack.  Four bytes of which are your "d", and the other four are whatever happen to be there.  In your example, e[0] and e[1].

If you want to print "d" as a float, you need to explicitly cast it, or assign to a float variable.  In either case, the compiler will convert it into a double before calling printf().  (Note: as odd as it may sound, "%f" is used to print doubles, not floats.  You can't print floats.  You can read floats, or doubles, with "%f" and "%lf", in scanf(), but in printf(), "%f" prints doubles.)

Comment: *"when you use a float in an expression, it is automatically converted into a double."* This is false. Floats do not get implicitly converted to double on all expressions, unless other operand in expression is double (*Usual arithmetric conversion*). What you are after are called *default argument promotions*, which happen **only** when A) float is passed to function without prototype, or B) float is passed to function which takes variable arguments (prototype ends with `, ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are pulling 8 bytes off the stack - four of which are 0x00000012, the rest being compiler-dependent (perhaps the return address which was pushed onto the stack when the stack frame for printf was constructed).