# Printing an integer as a Floaing point number

Tags: c, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is printf’s behaviour when printing an int as float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203754/what-is-printfs-behaviour-when-printing-an-int-as-float)

```
int main()
{
 int x=4;
 int y=987634;
 printf("%f %f",x,y);
}
```

On compiling this code i get an output as 0.000000 0.000000. Shouldn't there be a type promotion of x and y to floating point numbers? Shouldn't the O/P be 4.000000 and 987634.000000?
Can anyone help me with this. Thanx in Advance.

Comment: I can't quite find an *exact* duplicate, but this type of question has been asked [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398791/how-is-conversion-of-float-double-to-int-handled-in-printf) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632080/print-the-float-value-in-integer-in-c-language) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203754/what-is-printfs-behaviour-when-printing-an-int-as-float).

Comment: I'd be pleased to see anything of this type. Can u post the links.
@AdamRosenfield

Comment: But why is it always Zero? Shouldn't the result be the integer equivalent of the set bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conversions happen to arguments to functions with a prototype which includes the specific parameters. The prototype for `printf()` does not include the specific parameters after the first one

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

so, no arguments after the 1st one get automatically converted except as defined by "default argument conversions" (basically any integer type with a rank lower than `int` to `int` and any floating-point type with a rank lower than `double` to `double` (*thank you, Pascal Cuoq*)). You need to convert them explicitly yourself with a cast operation

```
    printf("%f %f\n", (double)x, (double)y);
```

Ohhh ... and you really, really, really should include the header that has the prototype in question (under penalty of Undefined Behaviour)

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Just a note regarding “no arguments after the 1st one get converted automatically”: there are promotions applied to the arguments in the ellipsis. They are called “default argument promotions” and they do not include promotion from `int` to `double` (C99 6.5.2.2:7)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no idea that your `printf` format string is going to interpret the arguments as floats. It passes them straight through as `int`s.

Because `printf` is a varargs function, it's really up to you to pass parameters that make sense.

Comment: If it's a decent compiler, it will look at the format string and warn about it if you ask it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try `printf("%i %i",x,y);` to print integers as `4 987634`. For `printf` formatting details see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

`int`s and `float`s are stored differently in memory, but your compiler does not know that you want floats. You need to convert them explicitly.

```
printf("%f %f",(float)x,(float)y);
```

Comment: Since variadic arguments are default-promoted, that does the right thing, but it is somewhat misleading. You should directly cast to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Variadic functions (printf() is one) aren't type checked because variadic signatures don't contain any type information. Thus, there's no implicit type casting. You have to do it manually:

```
printf("%f %f", (double)x, (double)y);
```