# Output of pointer code

Tags: c, pointers

Why is the output of the following C code 0.000000?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(float *);

int main()
{
    int i = 10, *p = &i;
    foo(&i);
}

void foo(float *p)
{
    printf("%f\n", *p);
}
```

Please explain your answer.

Comment: You got your types mixed up...

Answer (score 3):

You are making `printf()` interpret the bits of an integer as if they were the bits of a float. This is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504148/what-can-happen-if-printf-is-called-with-a-wrong-format-string).

What result did you expect?

Comment: Why there was no type casting. I expected 10.000000

Comment: @user2653926 When would that happen? There is no way for `foo()` to know that you lied. You should be getting compiler warnings however, since you're calling `foo()` with an argument of the wrong type.

Comment: Sorry still dont get it.

Comment: To start with you are sending an int into a function that takes a float. What compiler warnings/errors are you getting? Always try to hear what the compiler is saying about your code. So change the type of i to float and you are on your way to a better place...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when your code looks like it does in your question the line `*p = &i;` doesn't do anything at all.

Next - you are passing a pointer to your `int` variable to a function that expects `float`. Like @unwind mentioned in the comments there is no way for `foo()` to know that you lied.
Typecasting is different thing from what you seem to consider it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(float *);
int main()
{
    int i = 10; //try this and see it fails, 
                //then switch this line with float i = 10; and try again
    foo(&i);
}
void foo(float *p)
{
    printf("%f\n", *p);
}
```

EDIT> If you insist on having a typecast somewhere...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(float *);
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    float p = (float)i;
    foo(&p);
    return 0;
}
void foo(float *p)
{
    printf("%f\n", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) in C and C++ take variable number of arguments while they don't know type of entry arguments.

In [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function, the first argument is a string which hopefully indicates the types of following arguments by *format specifiers*.

In your code, your specifier indicates that the following argument is an float (`%f`), but you've passed an integer. Since all this type checking is happening in run-time and compiler knows nothing about it, there is no automatic casting.

Your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: The actual parameter has static type `float`.  Its runtime behavior is defined because of a strict aliasing rule violation.  But the problem is not with the variadic function call.  One could write `float x = *p;` and the problem would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int *);
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    foo(&i);
}
void foo(int *p)
{
    printf("%f\n",(float) *p);
}
```