# Printing floating point using integer type specifier

Tags: c

I have the below C code.

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n",5/(float)4.7);
    printf("Size of int = %d",sizeof(int));
    return(1);
}
```

But the result is 1610612736
I was expecting the result to be 1 since we are tying to print an integer. Why this is the case? How float value is getting converted to a large value in printf statement?
I am using codeblock + mingw

Comment: What is going on?  Is it 'Bad Specifier Day' or something?

Comment: Please use a language with strong typing, e.g. Python.

Comment: @MartinJames Today is `%d`-day.

Comment: @MartinJames the question is not a duplicate. The OP didn't realize that `5/(float)4.7` leads to a float value. But he wants to print an integer (and correctly has `%d` format specifier).

Comment: [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714), [What can happen if printf is called with a wrong format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14504148/995714)

Comment: The `printf("Size of int = %d",sizeof(int));` also has a mismatch between the format specifier and the type of the value it corresponds to. It should be `printf("Size of int = %zd",sizeof(int));` or `printf("Size of int = %d",(int)sizeof(int));`, although it would be better to use `printf("Size of int = %zu",sizeof(int));` or `printf("Size of int = %u",(unsigned int)sizeof(int));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you're *trying to print an integer* you have to cast the result to `int`

```
printf("%d\n",(int)(5/(float)4.7));
```

otherwise `5/(float)4.7` is a `float`

You see `1610612736` because the `float` value is "**interpreted**" as and `int` leading to and odd result.