# How do I print out the first number typed?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    float number[6];
    for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {
        printf("write number %i\n", i+1);
        scanf("%i",&number[i]);
    }
    printf ("the first number you wrote: %i", number[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble understanding how to print out the first number in an indexed variable. The answer is always `0`, if i type `number[1]` or `number[5]` the output is always `0`

Comment: `number` is an array of `floats` but you are scanning `int`.

Comment: In addition to that , you are attempting to print **the second** number.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are **zero-based**. And in C++, you should use `std::cout` and `std::cin`, not the old C functions, especially not the particularly error-prone `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know what to write when im printing out the first number, the is answer always 0.

but from this statement it's clear that you are not printing the first number entered

```
printf ("the first number you wrote: %i", number[1]);
```

as `number[1]` refers to the **second number** you entered, try using `number[0]` instead of `number[1]`

```
printf ("the first number you wrote: %i", number[0]);
```

apart from the above one, there is one more problem.**you are using the wrong format specifier** for `float` in your `scanf()` and `printf` statements

use `%f` when scanning or printing `float`'s, `%i` is for `int`'s

generally using wrong format specifiers results in undefined behavior, have a look at this :  **[What can happen if printf is called with a wrong format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504175/5281962)**

additionally, try avoiding the use of `printf()` an `scanf()` and use `std::cout` and `std::cin` as others have pointed out.