# Unable to understand output produced after typecasting in c in little endian machine

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Below is the C program and the output is 201. I have no idea how this is possible. Please explain this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main() {
    int number = 288;
    char * ptr;
    ptr = (char * ) & number;
    printf("%x", * ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("%x", * ptr);
    return 0;
  }
```

This is in case of little endian machine. This question was asked in the MCQ contest on geeksforgeeks. But they provided no explaination of it.

Comment: UB . Printf if expeting unsigned int but is getting the char.

Comment: Any reasons for down vote?

Comment: @P__J__ can you provide any reference for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504148/what-can-happen-if-printf-is-called-with-a-wrong-format-string before asking use search

Comment: @P__J__ I wasn't aware of exact question to ask that what is this weird behaviour according to me. So I search for my code but couldn't find anything. That is why I asked.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore There is no undefined behavior in this case. It is a valid use of printf. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 201 is perfectly reasonable (on little-endian systems):

The variable `number` starts with these two bytes (on little-endian systems): 0x20, 0x01.

Comment: ... so, between your two `%x` you should probably insert a comma. And also insert 0x to make it visible that these are bytes printed as hex

Comment: I totally ovelooked hexa decimal specifier. I was interpreting it as decimal. Thanks a lot.